# Web Scraping by Using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, single-page-application

How can I use the json module to extract the price from provides the data in `JSON` format in an inline `script`?

I tried to extract the price in https://glomark.lk/top-crust-bread/p/13676
But I couldn't to get the price value.

So please help me to solve this.

```
import requests
import json

import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'bs4.zip')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user_agent = {
                 'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/35.0.1916.47'
                 }
headers = user_agent

url = 'https://glomark.lk/top-crust-bread/p/13676'
req = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

products = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "details col-12 col-sm-12 
col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-xl-5")
for product in products:
    product_name = product.h1.text
    product_price = product.find(id = 'product-promotion-price').text
    print(product_name)
    print(product_price)
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab json data(price) from hidden api using only `requests` module. But the product name is not dynamic.

```
import requests
headers= {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
   }

api_url = "https://glomark.lk/product-page/variation-detail/13676"


jsonData = requests.post(api_url,  headers=headers).json()

price=jsonData['price']
print(price)
```

Output:

```
95
```

Full working code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers= {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
   }

api_url = "https://glomark.lk/product-page/variation-detail/13676"


jsonData = requests.post(api_url,  headers=headers).json()

price=jsonData['price']



#to grab product name(not dynamic)

url = 'https://glomark.lk/top-crust-bread/p/13676'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

title=soup.select_one('.product-title h1').text
print(title)
print(price)
```

Output:

```
Top Crust Bread
95
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned content is provided dynamically by `JavaScript` so one of the approaches could be to grab the data directly from the script tag, what you already figured out in your question.

```
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('[type="application/ld+json"]').text)
```

will give you a dict with product information:

```
{'@context': 'https://schema.org', '@type': 'Product', 'productID': '13676', 'name': 'Top Crust Bread', 'description': 'Top Crust Bread', 'url': '/top-crust-bread/p/13676', 'image': 'https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/350001--01--1555692328.jpeg', 'brand': 'GLOMARK', 'offers': [{'@type': 'Offer', 'price': '95', 'priceCurrency': 'LKR', 'itemCondition': 'https://schema.org/NewCondition', 'availability': 'https://schema.org/InStock'}]}
```

simply pick information is needed like price:

```
data['offers'][0]['price']
```

##### Example

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://glomark.lk/top-crust-bread/p/13676'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

data = json.loads(soup.select_one('[type="application/ld+json"]').text)

product_price = data['offers'][0]['price']
product_name = data['name']
product_image = data['image']

print(product_name)
print(product_price)
print(product_image)
```

##### Output

```
Top Crust Bread 
95 
https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/350001--01--1555692328.jpeg
```

Comment: Just to be able to assess it better - You first accepted the answer and then rejected it again in next moment - Because you wanted to accept both, which unfortunately is not possible or because the answer actually does not fit?